# org.apache.spark.util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, heap-memory

I get the following error on executors while running my spark job. I am reading data from Database. The data has a string in UTF8

`Iterator<Row> t.next().getString(row.fieldIndex("short_name"));`

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler  - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 359,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromAddress(UTF8String.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getUTF8String(UnsafeRow.java:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.STRING$.getField(ColumnType.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.STRING$.getField(ColumnType.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.RunLengthEncoding$Encoder.gatherCompressibilityStats(compressionSchemes.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$$anonfun$gatherCompressibilityStats$1.apply(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$$anonfun$gatherCompressibilityStats$1.apply(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.gatherCompressibilityStats(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:74)
```

I am processing 100 GB of data with 10 executors of 14G. I started with 12G executors and I get the same error even with 14G and 3G Overhead memory.